# C++ Custom iterator for circular buffer, how to implement end()?

Tags: c++, c++20

I have written a circular buffer of size N. I've also written a custom iterator.

I'm using them for logic like this:

```
auto iter = circular_buffer.begin();
while(iter != circular_buffer.end())
{
    ++iter;
}
```

What is the implementation for `end()`? Usually it should point to the last element + 1, but if the buffer contains N items, last element + 1 will be the first element and the above code won't even loop once. I cannot do:

```
do
{
   ++iter;
} while(iter != circular_buffer.end());
```

because if the buffer is empty, it will execute once.

Is there a way to solve this?

Comment: When the buffer is full, are all spaces used? That would make things complicated...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note: the following assumes that the circular nature of the buffer is a property that is being exposed to the user for their use, rather than being an implementation detail of the system (as is the case for `std::list` implementations).

Giving a circle a proper "range" is something of a problem since... it's a circle. It conceptually has neither a beginning nor an end.

One way to do this is to make the "circle" into a helix. Every iterator stores both whatever normal information it needs as well as a cycle count. When an iterator is incremented to whatever the arbitrary "beginning" of the list is, the cycle count is incremented. If the iterator is decremented to before the beginning of the list, the cycle count is decremented. Two iterators are only equal if their position *and* cycle counts are equal.

Most iterators created by the circular list should have a cycle count of zero on construction. The `end` iterator should have a cycle count of 1 while having the same position in the circle as the `begin` iterator.

Of course, there are some implementation problems. Doing this requires that every iterator's increment/decrement operations to know where the "beginning" of the circle is. So they all need a pointer to the first element or something. But if they have that, then these iterators all become invalid if you modify the list, since that can change what the "first element" is. Now, invalidating iterators on container modification is something that is true of many container iterator types, so it's not too big of a problem. But it is something you should be aware of.

That's kind of an unavoidable downside of trying to use ranges with a concept that inherently has neither a beginning nor an end.

Comment: I'd guess that the "circular" aspect is more an implementation detail, while for the user it's just like a vector or something (eg. popping from the front becomes an `O(1)` operation, as we just move where the `begin` ptr is). But this underlines that the question should've been clearer on what the behaviour ought to be.

Comment: I'd actually flip the POVs around. For the user, it's circular as that's how it was written to behave. The implementation detail is whether it's a vector or deque or linked list or whatever.